# How do you access THREE.Geometry?

Tags: geometry, three.js

How can you create a multi faceted object like say in a shape of the mountain? Without resorting to something like THREE.PlaneGeometry? Can you use THREE.Geometry instead?

Answer (score 0):

Three.PlaneGeoemtry is only a preset for the user that already generates the vertex positions and UV-coordinates for you. For creating a mountain, you should stick to Three.PlaneGeometry and move the vertices up and down, depending on some height values of any kind you wish (function, or height map texture or whatever). You could also create your own Three.Geometry object but in the end, I think, you will end up with something very close to PlaneGeometry.